# How can React components count themselves in a Context?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to write React components that wrap a Context provider/consumer.

The provider wrapper knows how many consumers it contains. It can contain "anything", so just counting children doesn't work here.

The consumers know their rank. In other words, the first consumer knows it's the first one, etc.

For example:

```
<MyProvider> {/* knows there are 3 consumers */}
  <div>
    <MyConsumer/> {/* knows it's the first consumer */}
  </div>
  <MyConsumer/> {/* knows it's the second consumer */}
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <MyConsumer/> {/* knows it's the third consumer */}
</MyProvider>
```

The following code **doesn't work** but gives an idea of how a consumer could look like:

```
const MyConsumer = () => {
  const value = useContext(MyContext);
  const rank = value.rank;
  value.rank++; // No! Context doesn't work that way!

  return (<p>I'm consumer {rank}</p>);
}
```

I tried various techniques, tried to share provider-level state via the context... But I couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator covers most of the requirements above, although not all (especially the "rank").

I ended up writing [an `Iterator`, which is part of Nstal.](https://github.com/nstaldev/nstal/blob/main/packages/react-core/src/Iterator.tsx)